# Pandas replace values in dataframe timeseries

Tags: python, replace, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df with pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex as index.

The data is like this:

```
Time                 Open  High Low   Close Volume
2007-04-01 21:02:00 1.968 2.389 1.968 2.389 18.300000
2007-04-01 21:03:00 157.140 157.140 157.140 157.140 2.400000
```

....

I want to replace one datapoint, lets day 2.389 in column Close with NaN:

```
In: df["Close"].replace(2.389, np.nan)
Out: 2007-04-01 21:02:00      2.389
     2007-04-01 21:03:00    157.140
```

Replace did not change 2.389 to NaN. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`replace` might not work with floats because the floating point *representation* you see in the `repr` of the DataFrame might not be the same as the underlying float. For example, the actual Close value might be:

```
In [141]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Close': [2.389000000001]})
```

yet the repr of `df` looks like:

```
In [142]: df
Out[142]: 
   Close
0  2.389
```

So instead of checking for float equality, it is usually better to check for closeness:

```
In [150]: import numpy as np
In [151]: mask = np.isclose(df['Close'], 2.389)

In [152]: mask
Out[152]: array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

You can then use the boolean mask to select and change the desired values:

```
In [145]: df.loc[mask, 'Close'] = np.nan

In [146]: df
Out[146]: 
   Close
0    NaN
```

Comment: It worked! I am a bit confused though, in the source csv it's exactly 2.389 - why did the value change after loading it into the dataframe? All I did was import like this: `df = read_csv("data.csv", parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True, index_col=0)`

Comment: [The floating point representation of decimals is not exact](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error). So when the CSV string "2.389" is parsed into a float, the floating is not exactly 2.389; it is instead the number closest to 2.389 which is representable as a float. [To see the exact value](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations) stored in a Python float use `Decimal`. For example, `import decimal`, `decimal.Decimal(2.389)` yields `Decimal('2.388999999999999790389892950770445168018341064453125')`

Comment: Also note that the DataFrame is storing the float in a NumPy array of dtype float32 or float64 -- a 32-bit or 64-bit float. On my (64-bit) machine, `pd.DataFrame([[2.389]]).iloc[0,0]` returns `2.3889999999999998`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the result to `df['Close']` or pass param `inplace=True` : `df['Close'].replace(2.389, np.NaN, inplace=True)`

e.g.:

```
In [5]:

df['Close'] = df['Close'].replace(2.389, np.NaN)
df['Close']
Out[5]:
0      2.389
1    157.140
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Most pandas operations return a copy and some accept the param `inplace`.

Check the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas.Series.replace

Comment: Unfortunately in this case it did not work, but if replace would actually find the value, this would be the way to go.

Comment: I think unutbu's answer is the obvious correct answer, strangely for me it worked fine without having to do anything special